# How to test java -XX:ErrorFile option is set properly on Windows

Tags: java, fatal-error, error-logging

### Background

- You can use `java -XX:ErrorFile=C:\path\to\file` to specify the path of fatal error log.
- To test that the `-XX:ErrorFile` option is set properly, you can use the `kill -SIGSEGV` command in the Linux environment.

### Problem

In the Windows environment, I could not find the equivalent of `kill -SIGSEGV`. I have tried to kill the `java.exe` process from Windows Task Manager, but the fatal error log was not created.

You can use `-Xmx` option like `java -XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx8m -XX:ErrorFile=C:\path\to\file` to cause `OutOfMemoryError` intentionally, but I don't want to change current JavaVM command-line option.

### Question

Is there any way to test the setting of the `-XX:ErrorFile` option in the Windows environment?